# using wp enqueue style to create a CSS file specifically for a page template

Tags: php, child-theme, wp-enqueue-style, code, theme-twenty-fifteen

I am trying to create a CSS file that only works for one page template. I am trying to do it using wp enqueue style but to no avail so far.

I was able to get it to work (sort of) using the following in my header.php.

```
   <?php if( is_page_template('background-slider-template.php') ) { ?> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/background-slider-template.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <?php } ?>
```

I know that is not the proper way to I tried the following using wp enqueue style.

```
function register_more_stylesheets() {
    wp_register_style( 'stylesheet_name', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/styledtwentyfifteen/background-slider-template.css' );
}
function add_my_stylesheet() {
    if ( is_page_template( '/styledtwentyfifteen/background-slider-template.php' ) ) { // using page slug
    wp_enqueue_style( 'stylesheet_name', get_stylesheet_uri() . '/styledtwentyfifteen/background-slider-template.css');  // no brackets needed for one line and no else
}
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_more_stylesheets' ); // should I use wp_print_styles hook instead?
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_stylesheet' );
```

It didn't work at all, although I feel like I am close.

I don't know if this affects anything but I am using a Child theme of the Twenty Fifteen theme to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have `get_stylesheet_uri` instead of `get_stylesheet_directory_uri`.

Answer (score 1):

If "/styledtwentyfifteen" is your child directory then that's included by `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` (of which `bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')` is an alias) so you should leave it out on registering:

```
function register_more_stylesheets() {
    wp_register_style( 'stylesheet_name', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/background-slider-template.css' );
}
```

Similarly with `is_page_template()` you only need the file name (relative to the template directory), and if you register a style you should just use its handle when enqueuing:

```
function add_my_stylesheet() {
    if ( is_page_template( 'background-slider-template.php' ) ) { // using page slug
        wp_enqueue_style( 'stylesheet_name' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason this is not working. I have no idea why but it doesn't seem to work. I feel like I have tried every piece of code out there for this but none of them seem to work.

Comment: Oh that's disappointing, can't think what's going wrong. Still, at least the "header.php" method works for you (and it's not really that bad a way to do it really)...

Comment: Yes, that is working for me at least. I think it may be my theme and child theme that is causing the issue. Anyway, for now at least I have a way to achieve it. Thanks for your help.